# Cannot use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request as Request because the name is already in use

Tags: laravel

quiero recibir en un controlador unos datos por método post desde un formulario. sigo los pasos que me dictan en el curso y este me dice que en el controlado debo requerir la siguiente linea

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request
```

pero me sale el suguiente error

> "Cannot use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request as Request because the name is already in use".

Estoy trabajando con laravel.

Gracias

---

"Este es el codigo del controlador. El segundo 'use' (useIlluminate\Support\Facades\Request;) es el que no me funciona."

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

    class PeliculaController extends Controller
    {
        public function index($pagina = 1)
        {
            $titulo = 'Listado de mis peliculas';

            return view('pelicula.index', [
                'titulo' => $titulo,
                'pagina' => $pagina
            ]);
        }

        public function formulario()
        {
            return view('pelicula.formulario');
        }

        public function recibir(Request $request)
        {
            $nombre = $request->input('nombre');

            var_dump($nombre);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La documentación nos indica al respecto del uso de la clase [`Request`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#accessing-the-request) que se obtiene mediante el namespace:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

La cual te da acceso por medio de inyección de dependencias a la petición HTTP de esta forma:

```
public function metodo(Request $request)
{
    .....................
}
```

Una vez hecho lo anterior, por medio del objeto `$request` tenemos acceso a distintos métodos tanto del *trait InteractsWithInput* ubicado en: `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Concerns\InteractsWithInput` como de la clase en si misma.

Entonces invocar a:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request
```

- En este contexto no es estrictamente requerido
- Aqui te recomiendo leer sobre el  [*service container*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container#introduction)
- De hecho dentro de ella (*la fachada*) puedes observar que la tag `@see` nos referencia a la clase expuesta al inicio de esta respuesta de esta forma:

  ```
  @see \Illuminate\Http\Request
  ```

**Importante**: Si por alguna razón debes trabajar tanto con la fachada como con la clase en si misma, debes darle un alias a alguna de las 2 para evitar la duplicidad de nombres de esta forma:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request as Peticion;
```

Entonces cuando necesites a la fachada debes trabajar con el alias de la clase